# How to sprintf vector of mixed types and strings up to n digits precision?

Tags: r, printf

I have a vector consisting of mixed double precision values and very short strings of characters. I want to `sprintf` them, while showing results up to `n` digits. The problem is, I can't `sprintf` strings while using, for example `sprintf("%.8g", x)`, so I am using `"%.8s"` instead.

Because of that, if R writes the number in scientific notation, I am printing only beginning of the number and the results makes no sense. Simple example of this behaviour below:

```
koza <- c( pi, " > ", 2.01645169344289e-05)
sprintf("%.8s", koza)
```

What I receive is:

```
[1] "3.141592" " > "      "2.016451"
```

What I want to receive is either something like:

```
[1] "3.1415927" " > "      "0.0000202"
```

or

```
[1] "3.1415927" " > "      "2.0164517e-05"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: First thing is to try to convert to numeric first. if it is not na then use the sprintf function. `unlist(lapply(koza,function(x){ ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(x)), sprintf("%.8f",as.numeric(x)) ,x)}))`

Comment: @DJJ Thank you! Works great for formatting in what I do. I defined this as a custom function and use it instead of sprintf().

Answer (score 1):

Because you have mixed numbers and strings in this vector:

```
koza <- c( pi, " > ", 2.01645169344289e-05)
```

R has converted them all to character strings:

```
> koza
[1] "3.14159265358979"     " > "                  "2.01645169344289e-05"
```

So printing with a `"%s"` formatter will format it as a string, and so you'll only get the first N characters of `"2.01645169344289e-05"`.

```
> sprintf("%.4s", "abcdefghij")
[1] "abcd"
> sprintf("%.4s", koza)
[1] "3.14" " > "  "2.01"
```

You need to keep them as numeric as much as possible, format them as decimal numbers, and then paste them into strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was aware why is it happening that I lose digits and just like You say, I probably need to format them somehow, but I didn't know how to do this. I didn't really know about unlist(), lapply() and how to use them, but looks like solution provided by @DJJ works perfect for me :-) I defined this as a custom function and use it instead of sprintf().